# Pip not recognized to install program

Tags: python, instaloader

I'm trying to install instaloader and running into problems.

IU've downloaded the github file, extracted it, installed python and pip, i think. Now while runninng

```
pip3 install instaloader
```

in the windows command prompt its responding:

'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I've tried installing pip3 by running pip install pip in both python and command prompt, uninstalling and reinstalling python. Do i need to add python to the PATH?

Comment: yes, adding Python to PATH is very necessary, just Tick mark ADD TO PATH while installing python

Comment: Does this work? `python3 -m pip install instaloader`

Comment: I already installed it and reinstalling doesn't give that option.

Comment: Sometimes, pip3 is simply installed as pip. Most likely, `pip install instaloader` is all you need to do. But you have to be careful to check that the pip you are running is associated with the python you are running. `pip --version` should confirm that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install pip by 'python get-pip.py' rather than 'pip install pip'.

Comment: In the python shell or command prompt?